# Parity version while running

Tags: parity, nodes

I'm running a Parity node in a docker container. I've installed it with `docker pull parity/parity:stable` some time ago.

How can I know which version of Parity I'm running? (without stopping the node).

If I log in the container I can only see a constant stream, such as:

```
2019-07-03 11:52:51 UTC Imported #8078283 0x56bf…bf65 (181 txs, 7.98 Mgas, 530 ms, 30.92 KiB)
2019-07-03 11:52:52 UTC eth_accounts is deprecated and will be removed in future versions: Account management is being phased out see #9997 for alternatives.
2019-07-03 11:52:54 UTC Imported #8078284 0xe819…c89d (3 txs, 3.79 Mgas, 276 ms, 2.01 KiB)
2019-07-03 11:53:00 UTC   31/50 peers   5 MiB chain 32 MiB db 0 bytes queue 95 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    1 req/s,   24 µs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get either the container ID or name of your running container:

- `docker ps`

Use either of the above to attach to the running container and bring up a shell:

- `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash`

Get the version:

- `parity --version`